# Sentence is not printing on browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried to examine and make correction repeatedly on my code but it's still not printing the sentence when I run the it on the browser.
Everything seems be correct to me but I have no idea why the `para.textContent` part is not printing?

**My Code:**

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');
const para = document.querySelector('p');

select.addEventListener('change', setWeather);

function setWeather() {
  const choice = select.value;

  switch (choice) {
    case 'sunny':
      para.textContent = 'It is a beautiful day today ! Let\'s go to the park, take a walk outside !';
      break;

    case 'rainy':
      para.textContent = 'It\'s rainy outside. Don\'t forget to bring an umbrella if you want to walk outside.;
      break;

    case 'snowing':
      para.textContent = 'It\'s snowing outside. Just stay at home, sit by the window, sip your tea while reading book and watch outside.';
      break;

    case 'overcast':
      para.textContent = 'It isn\'t raining, but the sky is grey and gloomy, it could turn any minute, so take a rain coat just in case.';
      break;

    default:
      para.textContent = ''
      ';   
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <label for="weather"> Select weather type today: </label>
  <select id="weather">
    <option value=""> --Make a choice--</option>
    <option value="sunny"> Sunny </option>
    <option value="rainy"> Rainy </option>
    <option value="snowing"> Snowing </option>
    <option value="overcast"> Overcast </option>
  </select>

  <p></p>
</body>
```

Comment: You have couple of typos: You are missing closing ' tag in case: rainy, and you have three (3) ''' in your para.textContent, and there should be only 2 : ''

Comment: You just messed with your single quotes. One missing in line 28. One too much in line 40.

Comment: Woaa...it was the triple quotes( ' ' ' ) that has caused all the text to not appear on the page. Didn't expect that. I thought that even if there's a mistake there, the correct code still should be displayed...but it's not. Thanks for pointing out. Even one extra (') would cause a trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You had not used quotes properly hence you were getting error. Try to use double quotes `""` just to make the code more legibile.

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');
const para = document.querySelector('p');

select.addEventListener('change', setWeather);

function setWeather() {
  const choice = select.value;

  switch (choice) {
    case 'sunny':
      para.textContent = "It is a beautiful day today ! Let\'s go to the park, take a walk outside !";
      break;

    case 'rainy':
      para.textContent = "It\'s rainy outside. Don\'t forget to bring an umbrella if you want to walk outside.";
      break;

    case 'snowing':
      para.textContent = "It\'s snowing outside. Just stay at home, sit by the window, sip your tea while reading book and watch outside.";
      break;

    case 'overcast':
      para.textContent = "It isn\'t raining, but the sky is grey and gloomy, it could turn any minute, so take a rain coat just in case.";
      break;

    default:
      para.textContent = '';   
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <label for="weather"> Select weather type today: </label>
  <select id="weather">
    <option value=""> --Make a choice--</option>
    <option value="sunny"> Sunny </option>
    <option value="rainy"> Rainy </option>
    <option value="snowing"> Snowing </option>
    <option value="overcast"> Overcast </option>
  </select>

  <p></p>
</body>
```